# Text Input to Hyperlink through submit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a questionnaire where specific answers will link to other of my webpages through submit. **How do I hyperlink specific answers in text input so that when the user clicks submit it sends them to the page specific to the answer given by the user?** I am somewhat new to html/css and have only done a bit of js. I have found different answers to some relatable questions but not truly specific to what I want.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Friendship Evaluator</h1></center>
<table width="60%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><h3>Choose your best friend:</h3>
<strong>
<p>Filip</p>
<p>David</p>
<p>Christopher</p>
</strong>
<p>Now type your <b>besties</b> name and pick a dish</p>
<form action="submit-friend">
<label for="Pizza"> 
  <input id="Pizza" type="radio" name="Pizza-Lasagna">Pizza 
</label>
<label for="Lasagna"> 
  <input id="Lasagna" type="radio" name="Pizza-Lasagna">Lasagna 
</label>
<br>

<input type="text" placeholder="Favorite Friend" required>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what you want in the form

Comment: I want to hyperlink on submit for specific answer in text input. Like if I type chocolate and submit it sends to my chocolate webpage.

Comment: ohhh i understand